# MySQL output masking (i.e. phone number, SSN, etc. display formatting)

Tags: mysql

Is there a built-in SQL function that will mask output data?

Let's say I have an integer column, that represents a phone number (for any country). Is there a better way to display the numbers than sub-stringing them apart, loading hashes, dashes and dot, then concatenating them back together?

I know several languages have a feature to simply mask the data as it is displayed instead of restructuring it. Does MySQL have something similar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, if you have any modifications or improvements please leave them as comments and I will update the code. Otherwise if you like it, don't for get to bump it. Enjoy!

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION mask (unformatted_value BIGINT, format_string CHAR(32))
RETURNS CHAR(32) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
# Declare variables
DECLARE input_len TINYINT;
DECLARE output_len TINYINT;
DECLARE temp_char CHAR;

# Initialize variables
SET input_len = LENGTH(unformatted_value);
SET output_len = LENGTH(format_string);

# Construct formated string
WHILE ( output_len > 0 ) DO

SET temp_char = SUBSTR(format_string, output_len, 1);
IF ( temp_char = '#' ) THEN
IF ( input_len > 0 ) THEN
SET format_string = INSERT(format_string, output_len, 1, SUBSTR(unformatted_value, input_len, 1));
SET input_len = input_len - 1;
ELSE
SET format_string = INSERT(format_string, output_len, 1, '0');
END IF;
END IF;

SET output_len = output_len - 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN format_string;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's how to use it... It only works for integers (i.e. SSN Ph# etc.)

```
mysql> select mask(123456789,'###-##-####');
+-------------------------------+
| mask(123456789,'###-##-####') |
+-------------------------------+
| 123-45-6789                   |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select mask(123456789,'(###) ###-####');
+----------------------------------+
| mask(123456789,'(###) ###-####') |
+----------------------------------+
| (012) 345-6789                   |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select mask(123456789,'###-#!##@(###)');
+----------------------------------+
| mask(123456789,'###-#!##@(###)') |
+----------------------------------+
| 123-4!56@(789)                   |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This was great, I used for a simple formating output. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Let's say your `People` table has `namelast`, `namefirst`, and `phone` fields.

```
SELECT p.namelast, p.namefirst,     
  CONCAT(SUBSTR(p.phone,1,3), '-', SUBSTR(p.phone,4,3), '-', SUBSTR(p.phone,7,4)) AS Telephone, 
FROM People p
```

The `CONCAT(SUBSTR())` uses the field name for the first position, character position for the second, and number of digits for the third. Using "AS Telephone" keeps your column heading clean in your query output.

*One note of caution: I'd recommend against using integers for phone numbers, social security numbers, etc. The reason is that you'll probably never perform numeric computations with these numbers. While there is the odd chance you'd use them as a primary key, there's always the possibility of losing digits from numbers with leading zeros.*

Comment: Depending on region, "numbers with leading zeros" may not be a risk (for example, the North American Numbering Plan only allows leading digits 2-9, while the UK has a leading zero on every area code but never a leading double-zero). However, the range of valid phone numbers far exceeds several numeric types: a ten-digit phone number, read as a number, probably exceeds the range of a 4-byte unsigned integer (max 4294967295), while an 8-byte integer is much more space than needed for any current numbering system while still not including *, #, and +.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mySQL does have formatting power:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format

But you've also almost answered your own question.  MySQL doesn't have the same amount of power to be able to easily write a formatter based on other criteria.  It can, with if statements, but the logic makes the SQL difficult to read at best.  So, if you were trying to have a formatter based on country code, for example, you would have to write a lot of logic into the SQL statement which isn't the best place for it, if you have the option of another language to parse the results.