# Mysql format a string like XXXXXXXXXXXX to XX-XX-XXXXXXX-X

Tags: mysql

I need a string that looks like XXXXXXXXXXXX to look like this XX-XX-XXXXXXX-X.  I don't know of a function or pattern tool in MySQL that can do this.  Do you?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL output masking (i.e. phone number, SSN, etc. display formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112718/mysql-output-masking-i-e-phone-number-ssn-etc-display-formatting)

Comment: Ronald, usually I would vote down and close a question like this. But this is your first question after a good history of answering. I respect that. check this link on regex with sql, hopefully it will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx. and please try more of your own work before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do that, in MySQL is to use an expression with the SUBSTRING and CONCAT functions, Like this:

```
CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(str,1,2), 
  '-',
  SUBSTR(str,3,2),
  '-',
  SUBSTR(str,5,7),
  '-',
  SUBSTR(str,12,1)
 ) AS formatted_str
```

Answer (score 3):

if the length of the string is fix, you can just simple string manipulation

```
SELECT pat,
       CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTR(pat,1,2), 
                       SUBSTR(pat,3,2),
                       SUBSTR(pat,5,7),
                       RIGHT(pat,1))
FROM   tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73a833/2)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this, I think that's exactly what you are look for.

[MySQL output masking (i.e. phone number, SSN, etc. display formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112718/mysql-output-masking-i-e-phone-number-ssn-etc-display-formatting)

Comment: Links to other SO questions should be a close request, not an answer.

Comment: @Barmar the 3 answers have different approaches - and I doesn't understand his down vote.

Comment: @AllysondePaula I'm not sure what that has to do with my comment. If Jordan wants to provide an answer, he should write something, not just post a link to another question. That belongs in a comment or close vote. I don't think I downvoted, I only do that when an answer is completely wrong.