# MySQL column: Change existing phone numbers into specific format?

Tags: mysql, phone-number

I have a MySQL column that contains phone numbers, the problem is that they're in different formats, such as:

- 2125551212
- 212-555-1212
- (212)5551212

I'd like to know if it's possible to take the existing 10 digits, remove the formatting, and change them all to this format: **(212) 555-1212**

Not a duplicate, as I'm looking to update several thousand entries instead of masking new entries.

Comment: You could write a nested SQL update statement with 3 cases (or however many number of formats) ... update the existing rows with the specific format desired.

Comment: You can use `REPLACE()` to replace specific characters. You can use `SUBSTR()` to extract specific ranges of characters. And you can use `CONCAT` to concatenate them into a new string. Which part of this isn't working for you?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617847/cleaning-out-a-field-of-phone-numbers-in-mysql for how to remove the special characters from the phone number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL output masking (i.e. phone number, SSN, etc. display formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112718/mysql-output-masking-i-e-phone-number-ssn-etc-display-formatting)

Comment: Do you have only North American numbers? If not, your format will not work for some of the numbers.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as I want to update existing entries, not mask new ones. Also, they are NA numbers only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, no `REGEXP_MATCHES()` or `TRANSLATE()` function comes with standard [`MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) installation (they do with [`Postgres`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)), so you could do this a way which I find really dirty, but it works.

1. First you cleanse your column by removing characters that aren't numbers using `replace()`
2. Then you take several parts of the string to separate them out using `substr()`
3. Finally, you concatenate them adding symbols between your substrings with `concat()`

If you have any more characters that you need truncate, just add another `replace()` on top of 3 already existing.

**Sample data**

```
create table nums ( num text );

insert into nums values 
    ('2125551212'),
    ('212-555-1212'),
    ('(212)5551212');
```

**Query formatting your data**

```
select 
  num, 
  concat('(',substr(num_cleansed,1,3),') ',substr(num_cleansed,4,3),'-',substr(num_cleansed,7)) AS num_formatted
from (
  select 
    num, 
    replace(replace(replace(num,'(',''),')',''),'-','') as num_cleansed
  from nums
  ) foo
```

**Result**

```
num             num_formatted
2125551212      (212) 555-1212
212-555-1212    (212) 555-1212
(212)5551212    (212) 555-1212
```

Click here <kbd>**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c2ee8/9)**</kbd> to preview output.

I'm leaving `UPDATE` statement as a homework for the reader.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) I don't like the way it's handled in MySQL - too much code, but if it works, we shouldn't discuss with it.

Comment: Agreed, especially if it's one of the only options to do.